# How to numerically integrate f(x) between a lower and an upper bound?

Tags: python, integral

I have been told to modify the code i had before to integrate between the lower bound a and upper bound b.This is done by adding another parameter, width. The integral can then be calculated by summing up lots of rectangles of with area (width*f(x)). An example of what I need to calculate is shown below

> Calculate the integrals of f(x)=x from 0 to 100.

My code I have to modify is this, this is used to calculate product, how do I modify this to calculate integrals?

```
def product(f, a, b):
    total = 1
    for i in range(a, b+1):
        total *= f(i)
    return total
```

Comment: looks like homework to me :\

Comment: and with if it is lol? @steffen

Comment: Then that is ok, if you make a reasonable intent to solve the problem yourself, post how far you got and state in the question that it is homework. see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited:**

Assuming your function `f(x)` calculates the functional value at `x`, you can do something like this:

```
def f(x): # define this according to your function.
    return x*x

def integrate(func, a, b, width):
    total = 0
    i = a
    while i <= b:
        total += func(i)
        i += width
    return total * width

width = 0.01
integral = integrate(f, 0, 100, width)
print(integral)
```

Output:

```
333283.3350000302
```

True value of the integral is 333333.333333, so the result is quite accurate.

**Edit:**

To use some other functions like `sin` or `cos`, you can use built-in functions, inside the function `f(x)` like this:

```
def f(x):
    return math.sin(x)
```

Then to integrate from 0 to pi, use this:

```
width = 0.01
integral = integrate(f, 0, math.pi, width)
print(integral)
```

Remember to import math using `import math`.

Comment: so could i declare def foo(x), return x and then how would i display print the answer? would i just pass foo, then 3 parameters?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to multiply by `width` only once, i.e. `return total*width`?!

Comment: do i not have to define x?

Comment: When i put it in python the result i get is 0? why is this

Comment: does the width =2 and integral = etc have to be in its own line as when i do it, it goes on a new different line each time. is this supposed to happen?

Comment: I dont mean line i mean like section, should the width = 2 etc be in its own section? or should that be within the defining of the myfunc?

Comment: Yeah i understand this all, but yet when i calculate the answer i still get 0 :/

Comment: Yeah i got that thanks so much. By any chance do you know how to define sin and pi. i need to find the integral from 0 to pi using sin. The function i am trying to use is below, but when i run it, it does not work?

def sine(x):
    return math.sineh(x)

width = 2
integral = integrate(sine, 0, math.pi, width)
print(integral)

Comment: Yeah i have done this, but when i run it, it says pi is not defined? Where exactly would i define it

Comment: import math

def integrate(f, a, b, width):
    total = 0
    for i in range(a, b+1, width):
        total += f(i)
    return total * width

def normal(x):
   return x

def double(x):
    return x*x

def sine(x):
    return math.sin(x)

width = 2
integral = integrate(sine, 0, math.pi, width)
print(integral)    This is my code for using pi but it doesnt work, why? ive imported the math library used math.pi and everything i dont understand

Comment: @TurtleDave I have added the complete code a long time age, but you are still not using that. Use the latest code I gave you. To calculate sin, modify f(x) using the code section in the second last section. Finally to integrate sin, use the last code section. The answer should be approximately 2.

Answer (score 1):

If your `width` needs to be something like 0.001, you'll have to use something else than `range`, as it can't deal with float values.

Try while loop:

```
def integral(f, a, b, width):
    total = 0
    i = a
    while i <= b:
        total += f(i)
        i += width
    return total*width
```

EDIT:
You can use it like this:

```
def foo(x):
    return x
a = 0
b = 1
width = 0.001

integrated = integrate(foo, a, b, width)
print(integrated)
```

Note that you don't have to declare `a`, `b`, and  `width` as variable; You can just pass them in directly.

Comment: You may want to consider changing the loop condition to `i <= b` instead.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ It's integration, so for approximation, I thought either < or <= should do. But... did I miss something?

Comment: When you use `i < b`, you are missing the functional value at `i = b`.